# iphone stop AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I want to stop the `AVAudioPlayer` when click on new tab. Stop an Pause button are working properly but if i am click on new tab bar the player is to be play in background so how can i stop the player.

I used:

```
-(void)stop_play
{
    [player stop];
    play.hidden=NO;
    stop.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you stop/pause the player in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you click on new tab,in your action method write code like this

```
if(audioPlayer.playing){
[audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when your AVAudioPlayer playing, set one bool var as YES.. than call stop maethod with passing this bool var.. like Code here

```
if(isPlay)
{
isPlay = NO;
[audioPlayer stop];
}
```

after than you play audio set bool var again YES...